# Solfege (aka Do Re Mi) in natural minor scale?

Tags: scales, solfege

Is there a **Do Re Mi Fa Sol La Ti Do** equivalent in the minor scale? If so how's it spelled and how's it sung (maybe someone has a link where someone sings it). Thanks

Comment: Did you check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Minor) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Chromatic_variants)?

Comment: If you can’t hear it? Are you asking what Solfege syllables are usually said when singing the natural minor scale or are you asking what the natural minor scale sounds like? Are you not sure how to play the natural minor scale for yourself?

Comment: So are you asking for a link to a video specifically? I'm not sure that kind of question is on-topic, if that's what you're looking for. Also, why don't you just re-write that song in a minor key and change the syllables as Dom explained in his answer?

Comment: Note: "Questions about transcribing or **finding a particular song**, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers."

Comment: Regarding whether "solfege would have a web site", solfege isn't an entity. It's not a person or a company or anything like that. it's an idea. Imagine asking "wouldn't the dominant seventh chord have a web site?" There are several web sites dedicated to explaining the solfege system. A web search should turn up hundreds, if not thousands. The Wikipedia page for it is linked in Dom's answer. You're welcome to roll back edits (I didn't edit your question), but I assure you, most of the users of this Stack **do** know what Solfege is.

Comment: @foreyez 1., asking for sound clips is off-topic here(requesting off-site resources). 2. Solfege is the correct terminology for the "Do Re Mi" system so using in the title helps others find it in the future (Do Re Mi is still in  the question so it will come up in a keyword search). See https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/question-cleanup-making-questions-findable-for-others for more information 3. If you know the natural minor scale you already know what the scale sounds like, you just have to put the syllables with it.

Comment: A minor scale is just a major scale down a third (syllable-wise) so I was taught to sing it:  La-Ti-Do-Re-Mi-Fa-Sol-La in natural minor.  Fa and optionally be replaced with "Fi" and Sol with "Si".

Comment: found it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLM3abLLUp0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, this notation is known as [*Solfege*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge), and there are two different types. *Fixed Do*, where C is always Do, and *Movable Do*, where the root of the scale you are using is Do. The rest of this answer will focus on Movable Do, as in Fixed Do the answer will differ based on what note you are starting on.

The major Solfege syllables are the ones that you listed (note, sometimes `Ti` is called `Si` instead):

```
Do Re Mi Fa Sol La Ti Do
```

The chromatic Solfege syllables are as followed with `i` typically raising a note and `e`typically lowering a note with the exception of Re that lowers into Ra:

```
Do Di/Ra Re Ri/Me Mi Fa Fi/Se Sol Si/Le La Li/Te Ti Do
```

To get any other scale just lower or raise the syllables as you would notes in the scale, so for natural minor Movable Do you get:

```
Do Re Me Fa Sol Le Te Do
```

Comment: Mi / me may be a challenge to distinguish for English speakers. I normally pronounce mi the same as the ordinary English word me (first person singular object pronoun).

Comment: @Remy more like meh

Comment: @Remy I only recently noticed this expanded solfege.  So, I have never said it nor heard it.  I need to talk to some of my more musically educated friends.  I got as far as Grade 8 Theory in the Associated Board scheme but that was a very long time ago.  I don't recall mention of this or indeed much mention of solfege at all.

Comment: @Dom: do you mean like mèh [mɛ]?

Comment: @Remy yes I couldn't find the right accents on my phone

Answer (score 5):

You can treat the minor tonic as Do of its own scale.  Or you can treat it as La of the relative major.  Either way, (for anything but the Natural Minor with La as tonic) you'll need 'accidentals'.

There are several systems of doing them in solfege.  Here's one:

The sharpened degrees are sung as Di ('Dee'), Ri, Fi, Si, Li. (There seems no need for a sharpened 3rd).

The flattened degrees are Raw, Maw, Saw, Law, Taw.

So, a harmonic minor scale would be Do, Re, Maw, Fa, So, Law, Te, Doh.    Or, in the 'relative' system: La, Te, Do, Re, Mi, Fa, Se, Do.

Here's (the beginning of) a discussion of this controversy from 1888, over 100 years ago!

https://www.jstor.org/stable/3360044?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Not sure if this is another cultural difference but in my experience, the flat three is spelled "Me" and pronounced like "May".

Comment: Penultimate para., last word - 'La'?

Comment: You would not need to raise Mi (or Ti) because they are already raised!  There is an actual reason for it beyond just "There seems no need for a sharpened 3rd".